# Gemara text with Nekudos

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, internet, vowels-nekudot, text

Does anyone know where to find a Gemara text with nekudot online? I'm having trouble finding one.

Comment: Since the posting of the answers below, Sefaria has started to add vowels to its texts. It doesn't seem to cover the entire Talmud yet, but it's worth checking.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on which tractate you're looking for, you could try [Tuvia's](http://www.tuvias.com/cats.asp?maincatid=256&categoryid=256) who also makes his texts available online for free at [e-daf.com](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp). (It's one of the "size" options in the dropdown. Note: they don't have all tractates.)  Greenfield Judaica also has the [Oz V'Hadar Menukad](http://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/talmud---gemara-oz-vehadar-menukad-edition.html).

For other online versions (which also don't appear to be complete as of this posting), see, e.g.:

- [Daf-Yomi.com](http://daf-yomi.com/Dafyomi_Page.aspx?vt=3&massechet=307&amud=3&fs=0)
- [KnowTheTorahByHeart.com](http://knowthetorahbyheart.com/gemora/gemora.html#link)
- [Daat.ac.il](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=567)
- [Wikitext](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%91%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%93_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%91)

See also [here](https://daf-yomi.com/content.aspx?PageId=162).

Comment: +1 for the e-daf suggestion. As far as Greenfeld Judaica, I think he's looking for an online text which includes *nekudot*, not a physical book.

Comment: The Koren Brachot is available in "look inside" on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Koren-Talmud-Bavli-Vol-1-Berakhot/dp/965301563X), after the index. It seems that the other volumes don't have "look inside" options.

Comment: @Ploni You might be right. I thought at first the OP was looking to order from online.

Comment: Generally, when someone says they want something online, they mean mamish online, not "to buy online".

Answer (score 3):

You can get 7 daf a week with nekudot on the dvar malchus from lubavitch as a PDF
http://dvarmalchus.org/Download.aspx?History=True
Online. The entire 7 year cycle. Scroll down towards the end of the pdf.

Comment: That would work better if there was an index of which daf is in which issue. Otherwise how would someone know where to find a specific page?